# view helper validation

Tags: validation, zend-framework, view-helpers

[ZF Manual on View Helpers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html)

According to the above link I can create a form element in the view like so

```
echo $this->formText($name, $value, $attribs);
```

However how would I apply validation or does this need to be done in the controller using the validator component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did this:-

```
<form action='/login'>
echo $this->formText($name, $value, $attribs);
echo $this->formSubmit($name, $value, $attribs);
</form>
```

Then you would carry out the validation in the indexAction of your login controller using the validators available in [Zend Validate](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.html).

Using this method you probably won't have a form object and I wouldn't really recommend using it unless you really don't like Zend Form.

So, basically that was just a long winded way of saying 'Yes this needs to be done in the controller using the validator component'.

Answer (score 0):

Better solution is to use complete Zend_Form class to create the form and validate it.